# What is the shortest way to delegate unimplemented methods to a contained object in Java?

Tags: java, composition

I am containing the "primary object" (with most of the features) within a "helper object" that will provide convenience methods.  I have only an Interface available, aside from a returned object with that interface from a factory method.  I am thinking a good way to "extend" this object is composition, but the problem that my superclass must implement the primary object's interface, which would be about 600 lines of stub code.

Clearly an uncomplicated but verbose solution would be to fill out all the stubs so they merely call the primary object's methods.  Is there a better way than this in Java?  In other languages I'm familiar with, there would be ways to do automatic delegation for methods that are not implemented in the helper object.

Example:

```
class Helper implements Interface {
    Primary primary;

    Helper(Primary _primary) {
        primary = _primary;
    }

    void helper() {
        doStuff();
    }

    // 500 lines of this
    void stub() {
        primary.stub();
    }
}
```

Note:

Original plan was to just use regular expressions to replace all the stub TODOs in Eclipse with the actual calls.  Will be looking for an Eclipse tool that does this automatically though.  Also, looks like extending the interface or using Proxy is better in the end, so will be pursuing that.

Comment: Eclipse can do this for you.  Right click -> Source -> Generate Delegate Methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possiblites.

---

**First:** Use an abstract implementation that delegates the calls.

```
abstract class InterfaceDelegator implements Interface {
  protected final Interface primary;
  public InterfaceDelegator() {
    this.primary = primary;
  }
  // implements all the calls as: primary.call(...)
}

class Helper extends InterfaceDelegator {
  // override just the methods you need
}
```

---

**Second:** Use the proxy (probably cleaner).

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html

```
final Interface primary = ...;
return (Interface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Inteface.class.getClassLoader(),
   new Class[] { Interface.class },
   new InvocationHandler() {
     public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
       // if m is a method that you want to change the behaviour of, return something
       // by default, delegate to the primary
       return m.invoke(primary, args);
     }
   });
```

The invocation handler will handle calls through executing a method that you have coded, an all the others would be delegated to the primary implementation.
Then, you can wrap a code like this in a method or another factory.

---

**Third:** Using the IDE to generate the methods *(as others pointed out)*.

Answer (score 15):

Use [Lombok's @Delegate annotation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html).

Second-fastest is to use your IDE; many have this functionality.

Third-fastest is to write a tiny little introspecter and dump them out yourself.

Comment: I am interested in your introspecter solution. Can you give me a few pointers on how to implement it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the lombok team do not recommend the use of @Delegate anymore. They plan to remove from future releases.

Comment: @Mr.Pichler Hrm; interesting. Do you have a link to the discussion around this?

Comment: @DaveNewton its on the official project page. "Current Status: Negative" https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate.html

Comment: @DaveNewton it's a pity, because this feature is really really useful.

Comment: @Mr.Pichler Ah, skipped over that. Reasoning makes sense though.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, anyway, I really wish this feature could continue.

Comment: Lombok's @Delegate does handle generics correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs support inheritance to delegation refactoring.  This will generate most of the code you need.

If you don't want to use this you can create a dynamic proxy to direct the method calls to a selection of implementing delegates.

Answer (score 1):

There are two choices of which you can choose only one: reduced verbosity or speed/performance. You can of course use a generic reflection based approach which would affect the runtime performance or go with Lombok / eclipse auto-generated methods and live with the verbosity/magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is too big.  Classes and interfaces tend to grow over time, and it's usually a lot more trouble than its worth to break them up.  Once you start wrapping a big class inside another, however, some cleanup may be in order.

In crude terms, what you want to do is break Interface into manageable pieces.  The original Interface loses a whole bunch of methods, but picks up a few to return objects implementing the other interfaces.  Now, instead of `container.getX();`, you would have

```
Interface  container = new Helper( primary );
Letter  li = container.getLetterInterface(); // Convenience Method
                                             // "li" comes straight from primary
int  x = li.getX();
```

Ideally `Interface` drops from over 100 methods to under 20.  The returned interface implementations can be the underlying Primary objects, or objects created by them.  (And in the latter case, as desired they can show either the data as of the time the method was called *or* the current values in `primary`.)  This basically lets you slip information straight from `primary` to the caller without bothering with convenience methods.

Do this right and your code will be a *lot* easier to manage in this and other situations.  But it is a lot of work, so if you know this the last thing you are going to do with this code, use one of the other solutions.